# MongoDB primary failure before write acknowledgement

Tags: mongodb

I have a question about the following scenario:

We have `w:majority` write. It get's to the primary oplog, it get's replicated in secondary oplog but the primary fails before acknowledgement from the secondary is sent.

As per my understanding it is possible that the secondary get's the update but since primary failed before it could respond to the client, the client will get an error. Therefore he will assume the operation was unsuccessful while it could be actually persisted after the secondary gets elected as the new primary. Is that correct?

If yes, then what would be the best approach to handle this problem.